# Shady engine in python doesn't seems to display beyond 16 frames

Tags: python, shady

I'm using Shady to display images (PILLOW images) in a loop. For that I'm using the following commands:

```
Shady.Require( 'numpy', 'Image' )

w = Shady.World(  )

s = w.Stimulus( imList )

s.frame = lambda t: t * 60
```

Where imList is a list of 60 PIL images. Somehow, Shady doesn't produce anything on my screen. But, if I reduce the size of the list to 17, then it works.

```
Shady.Require( 'numpy', 'Image' )

w = Shady.World(  )

s = w.Stimulus( imList[0:17] )

s.frame = lambda t: t * 60
```

I've no idea what is going on. I'm new to Shady and there is not much documentation that I can read to understand what is going on. I just want to display 60 images (at 60 FPS) in a loop. I thought the above code should do it. But it doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. Also, why does

```
s.frame = lambda t: t * 60
```

mean 60 FPS? I'm not sure I completely understand that as well. I tried to look for some explanation of s.frame and the lambda function but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for your attention!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Shady's [`Stimulus` constructor documentation](https://shady.readthedocs.io/en/release/source/Shady.html?highlight=multipage#Shady.Stimulus) (with emphasis added):

> `multipage` (bool) – If you set this to `True`, multiple image frames will loaded using the `LoadPages()` method: this transfers each frame to the graphics card as a separate texture, which you switch between using the `.page` property.
>
> By contrast, if you leave it at the default value `False`, multiple image frames are handled by concatenating them horizontally into a single texture, and you switch between them using the `.frame` property, which indirectly manipulates `.carrierTranslation`.
>
> You may need to use `multipage=True` for animated images that have a large width ***and/or high number of frames***, because the normal concatenation method may lead to the texture exceeding the maximum allowable width.

So:

```
w = Shady.World()
s = w.Stimulus( imList, multipage=True )
s.page = lambda t: t * 60  # note the use of .page rather than .frame
```

This is also explained in the [animated-textures](https://shady.readthedocs.io/en/release/auto/examples_animated-textures.html?highlight=multipage) demo. That demo also introduces you to the `lambda` idea, explaining that the property is being set to a function of time in seconds. This concept is explained in detail in the "Key Concepts" chapter "[Making Properties Dynamic](https://shady.readthedocs.io/en/release/auto/MakingPropertiesDynamic.html)". (I'm not sure how you have ended up with the impression that there is "not much documentation you can read".)

That specific function, `lambda t: t*60` takes in time `t` in seconds, multiplies it by 60 frames per second, and returns the result. If you multiply seconds by frames-per-second you get a frame number, which is what `s.frame` (or `s.page`) are expected to be.  When you assign to `.frame` or `.page`, the necessary rounding, and the wrapping-around modulo the number of available frames, will be handled automatically.

Your dynamic properties don't have to be lambdas. They can be any callable: a vanilla function, an object method, an instance of some full-blown custom class that defines a `__call__` method, ... whatever you like, as long as it takes precisely one argument. A `lambda` is just a compact and nicely oneliney option—see [How are lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128)

Comment: Amazing! You must be a genius :-). This works! Thanks so much for taking time to explain and also give the solution. Thanks again! Also, yes I see now that there is enough documentation. I guess I was just impatient having spent a couple of days with this. I'll read the documentation more before I ask the next question :-).

Comment: I'm glad it was useful.  If it solves your problem, please "accept" the answer using the green check-mark symbol to the left. That's how answers are validated here.

Comment: Got it! Accepted the answer.